# Template recursion with std::index_sequences/std::tuples: What is the compiler actually doing here?

Tags: c++11, templates, tuples, template-meta-programming, c++17

I found this pieces for C++17 of code in case std::tuple/std::index_sequence should be handled by recursion:

Example **1)**

```
template <class ... Ts>
constexpr T foo (const std::tuple<Ts...>&)
{ return ( bar(Ts{}) + ... ); }
```

In C++11/14 some people tend to use these approaches.

Example **2)**

```
auto res = 0;
using unused = int[];
(void)unused { 0, ((void)(res += bar(Ts{})), 0)... };
```

Example **3)**

```
auto res = 0;
const int dummy[] = {0, res += bar(Ts{})...};
(void) dummy;
```

However, there are two points which are not clear for me. Firstly, I want to know what the compiler is actually doing in **2)** and **3)**? Additionally, I noticed, that **3)** fails for complex types (e.g. `glm::vec3` and I wonder why not both fail, and both **2)** and **3)**, have problems in type deduction for `res` because auto is declared before the result can be added while iterating. Can this be circumvented without adding an additional template parameter in C++11/14? I also wonder why the brackets `Ts{}` are necessary for 3)?